# Optimal query for dense_rank to find multiples

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I'm querying a web traffic schema to determine which visits are initial and which a return.

I have two tables SESSION and ALIAS.

```
CREATE TABLE alias (
  person_id vachar(24),
  alias varchar(24)
)

CREATE TABLE session (
  session_id vachar(24),
  alias varchar(24)  -- FK to alias
  last_seen timestamp
)
```

The session table represents web visits for aliases, and alias table contains aliases for a person. I'm trying to create a view on session that will allow me mark a session as either "First Visit" **by a person** or "Return Visit" **by a person** (hence the join to alias below).

The solution I have thus far is using a window function with dense_rank as follows.

```
CREATE VIEW session_augmented as (
    SELECT S.session_id, S.last_seen, ....
     CASE 
        WHEN dense_rank() 
            OVER (partition by A.person_id COLLATE "C" ORDER by S.last_seen ) = 1 
        THEN 'First Visit' 
        ELSE 'Return Visit' 
     END as visit_type
    FROM session S
    JOIN alias A ON (S.person_alias = A.alias)

)
```

I've created indexes covering the range of queries including the join above.

The explain below shows a Seq Scan on session even though the person_alias column is indexed. Below is the explain:
https://explain.depesz.com/s/2LJ

The query runs slower than I'd like, is there a way to optimize? Is there a better approach that achieves the result I'm after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rank, Dense Rank and anything involving ordering is going to be average case *O(n log n)*, which for very large datasets can become quite oppressive.  In this case, I think you can get away with a `min` analytic function, which should be best, worst and average case *O(n)*.

```
SELECT S.session_id, S.last_seen, ....
 CASE 
    WHEN min (S.last_seen)
        over (partition by a.person_id) = s.last_seen
    THEN 'First Visit' 
    ELSE 'Return Visit' 
 END as visit_type
FROM session S
JOIN alias A ON (S.person_alias = A.alias)
```

While I doubt this matters for the circumstances you described, if it were theoretically possible for a person to log in twice at exactly the same time, then this would fail because it would return two records.  That said, your query would suffer from the same issue, and again I don't think it's even possible -- I just thought I'd bring it to your attention.

For what it's worth windowing functions are definitely the way to go.  The only sane alternative I see would be to write a wrapper in some programming language.  I doubt you would see much improvement over the `min` function.

Comment: Interesting solution. However wasn't really any faster than the one in the original question.

Comment: In fact by adding some indexes i was able to get my original query to perform the best: https://explain.depesz.com/s/m5E

Comment: That's interesting... out of curiosity, how many rows in your tables and how many rows in the final results?  It's just a guess, but I would think the index would help on the join but not necessarily on the grouping piece.

Comment: You can see from the explain there are about 900k in one table 770k in the other